# Does Inverse of Phi(N) Mod (N) always exist?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let N=pq where p and q are odd primes and let $\Phi(N)$ be Euler Phi function i.e. $\Phi(7) = 6$ since 6 numbers co-prime to 7

**Does the inverse of $\Phi(N) Mod(N^2)$ always exist?**

It exists if and only if $$gcd(\Phi(N),N^2) = 1 \leftrightarrow gcd(\Phi(N),N)=1$$

So my question comes down to proving $gcd(\Phi(N),N)=1$

I just want to know if the above statement is always true. I have tested it with some numerical values and it seems to be true so far.

A proof of that would be great but not necessary (if its too long).

Comment: $p,q=3,7$. In general, you need $p\not\mid q-1$ and $q\not\mid p-1$ then $\phi(N)$ is relatively prime to $N$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Why is that?

Comment: @SabihHasan Well, that follows directly from the fact that $\Phi (N) = (p-1)(q-1)$.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot! @Crostul and ThomasAndrews